# Angular not rendering italic text

Tags: html, angularjs, editor

I am using tinymce in the backend and I have configured it to use italic  tags for rendering italic text:

```
formats: {
        bold: {inline: 'b'},
        italic: {inline: 'i'}
    },
    valid_elements: "b,i,b/strong,i/em",
```

For the frontend I am using angular and when I render the text like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="article.text" class="article-text"></div>
```

The text that is created has italic text and the html looks like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="article.text" class="article-text ng-binding">
     <p><i>Italic</i> <strong>bold</strong></p>
</div>
```

But only the bold text is actually bold, the italic text is not rendered italic.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the same code and it's working fine, seems to be have an issue with some overriding CSS or some other. Please refer to the below link. http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAJRRIYXID6Y